# Exclude first row when importing data from excel into Python

Tags: python, pandas, import-from-excel

I have a partial code to import excel into Python as strings. How I can exclude first row when importing data from excel into Python?

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel(".xlsx", parse_cols="A,C,E,G, I, K, M, O, Q, S, U, W, Y, AA, AC, AE, AG, AI, AK, AM, AO, AQ, AS, AU, AW, AY, BA, BC, BE, BG, BI, BK, BM, BO, BQ, BS, BU, BW, BY, CA, CC, CE, CG, CI, CK, CM, CO, CQ, CS, CU, CW, CY, DA, DC, DE, DG, DI, DK, DM, DO, DQ, DS, DU, DW, DY, EA, EC, DE, EG, EI, EK, EM, EO, EQ, ES, EU, EW, EY")
data = data.to_string()
```

Comment: Are you looking to avoid the headers in `data`? Or do you have unnecessary rows in the excel. Using `skiprows()` to avoid reading in the header is probably not the right approach. You can do: `data.to_string(header=False)` to avoid the headers.

Comment: just `skiprows()` will do for me, thank you.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The pandas documentation for the `pd.read_excel` method mentions a `skiprows` parameter that you can use to exclude the first row of your excel file.

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx", parse_cols="A,C,E,G", skiprows=[0])
```

Source: [pandas docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html#pandas.read_excel)

Comment: Hi @Onel Harrison, could you help with this question?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46751996/selecting-and-importing-only-certain-columns-from-excel-for-importing

Comment: And if you want to skip first two rows then; 

`pd.read_excel("file.xlsx", parse_cols="A,C,E,G", skiprows=[0,1])`

Comment: Might be a version issue, but this worked for me instead of using an array:

data = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx", parse_cols="A,C,E,G", skiprows=1)

Answer (score 2):

for read_excel function assign value to `skiprows` argument. it will ignore the header

Comment: Note: `skiprows` doesn't mean that a `header` is not created from the first non-skipped row, `header=None` would avoid creating a `header` from the data

Answer (score 0):

**parse_cols** argument is deprecated since version 0.21.0. Instead you should use **usecols**:

usecols : int or list, default None

- If None then parse all columns, If int then indicates last column to
- be parsed If list of ints then indicates list of column numbers to be
- parsed If string then indicates comma separated list of Excel column
- letters and column ranges (e.g. “A:E” or “A,C,E:F”). Ranges are
- inclusive of both sides.

To exclude first row use **skiprows**=[0] argument.