# Selecting and importing only certain columns from excel for importing

Tags: python, excel, function, import-from-excel

'I have an excel file which contains many columns with strings, but i want to import certain columns of this excel file containing 'NGUYEN'.

I want to generate a string from columns in my excel which had 'NGUYEN' in them.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel("my_excel.xlsx", parse_cols='NGUYEN' in col for cols in my_excel.xlsx, skiprows=[0])
data = data.to_string()
print(data)


SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

my_excel.xlsx
[image]

Function output should be

```
data =  'NGUYEN VIETNAM HANOIR HAIR PANTS BIKES CYCLING ORANGE GIRL TABLE DARLYN NGUYEN OMG LOL'
```

Comment: Have you tried to define `cols` and then paste this as argument into `pd.read_excel`?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this is what you are looking for. I tried making it as simple and compact as possible, if you need help making a more readable multi-line function. Let me know!

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_excel("my_excel.xlsx")
getColumnsByContent = lambda string:  ' '.join([' '.join([elem for elem in data[column]]) for column in data.columns  if string in data[column].to_numpy()])
print(getColumnsByContent('NGUYEN'))
print(getColumnsByContent('PANTS'))
```